# accidentally ran sed command, does unknown option to `s' mean no substitution happened?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I accidentaly ran sed command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/http:\/\/i.po.st\/static\/v3\/img\/set-24.png/https:\/\/i.po.st\/static/v3/img/set-24.png/gI' {} \;
```

before I had finished escaping `/`

it errored out:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
```

so no weird substitution happened right?

Comment: you mean you did not take a backup before to be able to compare if something happened?

Comment: You can use a different separator character, by the way, so you don’t have to escape that much.  `'s|http://blah|http://bleh|gi'`

Comment: @OliverFriedrich I actually have, but I've ran two big seds before, and now diffs are too big to understand what happened. I tried to use -I flag to ignore other diffs.

Comment: well, you have the SEDs in your bash history... so you can always redo them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your postet cmdline I'd suggest that no substitution happened, as the command was not correct.

Anyway, I'd suggest that you either first check the results by suppressing the "-i" switch, or take a backup of the file before.

Comment: or use `-i'.bak'` to let `sed` create a backup file

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that nothing has been changed.

The `char 75`string printed in your error message refers to a failure in the substitution string which caused `sed` to exit before making any changes.